# How portable is this shell assignment?

Tags: shell

> VAR=${VAR:-value}

The purpose is to set the environment variable VAR to value unless it's already set.

I see it works in bash and dash, but how portable is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment is portable, it works in any POSIX shell. POSIX define [this expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) as:

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
>   word shall be substituted; otherwise, the value of parameter shall be
>   substituted.

But this also sets `VAR` to value if `VAR` was set and null. To set `VAR` to value unless it's already set, you must use:

```
VAR=${VAR-value}
```

Omitting the colon make substitution occur only if the variable is unset:

> In the parameter expansions shown previously, use of the colon in the
>   format shall result in a test for a parameter that is unset or null;
>   omission of the colon shall result in a test for a parameter that is
>   only unset.